# How do I run Flutter widget tests with shadows enabled?

Tags: flutter, widget-test-flutter

I'd like to render some of my Flutter golden files with shadows. How can I accomplish that?

Shadows are disabled by default:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart#L942

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [debugDisableShadows flag](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/debugDisableShadows.html).

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('my golden test with shadows enabled', (tester) async {
    // Enable shadows
    debugDisableShadows = false;

    await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget());
    await expectLater(find.byType(MyWidget), matchesGoldenFile('..'));

    // Set the flag back to normal
    debugDisableShadows = true;
  });
}
```

Note that you have to toggle the flag back to normal inside the test case (and not `setUp` / `tearDown`) - otherwise, it will fail.

This happens because [this check](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/5034d57546ba904a88a122088b425cc55495b7c3/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/binding.dart#L825-L828) is performed immediately after the body of `testWidgets()` completes, but before the test case is considered finished. Which is also before `tearDown()` is executed.

Comment: Thanks. My oversight here was not realizing that the flag could only be set within a test, and had to be set back after.

Comment: I totally had the same oversight as well, took me some time to realize what was up.